# Discord py: disable commands for specific users

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm making a discord bot with a simple game functionality. What I want to do is when players go on an "adventure", other commands such as "farming" and "cooking" will be disabled. I was able to do this with toggling certain commands but the problem is that it was universal. If one player was in an adventure, everyone else became unable to use the commands on the list.

**How would I make it so only the specific player on an adventure would be unable to use the other commands?**

P.S. the other commands are in other cogs hence the method I used

This is my code:

```
import discord, asyncio, math
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import Cog, command, cooldown, BucketType

from .. import DB

def setup(bot):
  bot.add_cog(Adventure(bot))  

class Adventure(Cog):      
  commands = ['harvest', 'plant', 'craft', 'cook', 'upgrade']
  def __init__(self, bot):
    self.bot = bot

  @command(name="adventure")
  async def adventure(self, ctx): 
    self.toggle_commands(False)

  @command(name="escape")
  async def escape(self, ctx): 
    self.toggle_commands(True)

  def toggle_commands(self, bool):
    for row in self.commands:
      self.bot.get_command(row).enabled = bool
```

Comment: You can add the users that are on an adventure to a list and check if the user is in that list before executing the rest of the farming or cooking commands.

Comment: I'm using a database for this bot so I thought that might be a solution but won't that kind  of slow down the bot if for every crucial command I had to check if that user is on the database? But if that's the only way, I don't mind since it'll be an easy process

Comment: As far as I know this is the only way to disable commands for specific users. Also, I doubt it would have a drastic impact on performance.

Comment: You're going to be read/write to the database anyway if you execute the commands. It's not that big of a deal. See command checks: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=check#discord.ext.commands.check

Answer (score 0):

When a user enters adventure mode, you can add their user ID to a JSON file. Then, while running a command, you can check if the command user has their ID in the JSON file. If they do, just return.